# How can I write special symbols in a Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion, special-characters

I would like to know if is there any link or documentation which explains how to write special symbols.

An example from Math.SE, like a pow or something, is this:

[image: Example equation. Written in MathJax it would be: $A\setminus(B\setminus C)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C)$]

And so on...

Sometimes people edit my questions because I don't understand how to write it correctly. For example, the expression above could be written like this

$$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap C)$$

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe I found https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Glorfindel: I'd like to suggest that this question is not quite a duplicate of the question you linked too. When I saw the question I assumed it was not necessarily about LaTeX. Sure enough, user Laurel below has an excellent answer that I can use as well as the OP.

Comment: The answer here says about the same as balpha's answer in the linked question; mchen's answer provides a way to use LaTeX commands on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

∖(∖)=(∖)∪(∩)

MathJax isn’t supported on most SE sites (including Stack Overflow), so you need to use plain text. If you’ve written MathJax, you can paste it into a question/answer draft on a site that does support MathJax, copy the output, paste it where you want to use it, and then delete the draft:

> [image: picture of draft]

For superscripts and subscripts you should use `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags.

The most complex formulas can’t be typed without MathJax, so in some cases you may need to use a screenshot of the rendered MathJax.

Comment: Ok, but the question is how to know how to write correctly these symbols. Let's say I need to write this symbol "U", how should I assume that it should be written like this `\cup`?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko As I said, you can write it in MathJax and use a draft on a MathJax enabled site to translate that into plain text, as I attempt to show in the screenshot. Does that make sense?

Comment: How could the plaintext possibly be rendered correctly on stackoverflow, even with copy & paste. Does it use the math symbols from the higher numbered Unicode planes?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Yeah it’s Unicode. The union character for example is [U+222A](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+222A)

Comment: Related: *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*' absolutely awesome *[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)*"

Comment: There are also some MathJax links on [Physics meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/804/123208)